# How to update a Gtk.Grid previusly added to Gtk.Window?

Tags: python, refresh, gtk3, pygtk

On python, I create a `Gtk.Window` and add it a `Gtk.Grid`. But, later in the code, I want to update this already defined Grid with a new Grid with new content.

So, naively, I try to get the first `Grid` object and assign to it the new value, but it doesn't work.

So, here is my minimal example code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# MWE for refreshing Gtk.Grid

import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk


class GridWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Reassigning Grid MWE")
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        # Declaring the first Grid
        grid1=Gtk.Grid()
        label1=Gtk.Label("foo")
        grid1.add(label1)

        # Declaring the second Grid
        grid2=Gtk.Grid()
        label2=Gtk.Label("bar")
        grid2.add(label2)

        # Adding the first Grid to the Window
        self.add(grid1)

        # Trying to replacing the first Grid by the second
        ##############################
        self.get_children()[0]=grid2 # <- The problem is here
        ##############################

screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
win = GridWindow()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

When I do `self.get_children()[0]=grid2` the first `Grid` should normally be replaced by the second one. But the window I get still show “foo” witch is the rendering of the first `Grid`.

So how to pick up the object witch contain the `Gtk.Grid` and replace it with the content of `grid2`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve...but this will work

```
##############################
self.remove(grid1)
self.add(grid2)
##############################
```